# How to Access the Decorated Class' Attributes from a Class Decorator through `functools.wraps`

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm following [David Beazley's Python Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340377)'s Class Decorator recipe, which seems more proper, since it uses `functools.wraps` to give the decorator better organization and properties.

However, it isn't very clear to me how (or if) to access the instance's attributes from within the decorator itself. Here is a snippet of the code:

```py
import time
import types
from functools import wraps

class TimeDecorator():

    def __init__(self, func):
        wraps(func)(self)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tic = time.time()
        func_return = self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)
        tac = time.time()
        total_time = round((tac - tic) / 60, 2)
        print(f'Operation Time: {total_time} min.')
        # print(self.__wrapped__.test_attr) # going to give an error...
        return func_return

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)


class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.test_attr = 0

    @TimeDecorator
    def do_something(self):
        time.sleep(1) # example of stuff only...
```

I've tried to access the instance from the decorator's `__call__` through `self.__wrapped__.test_attr` or `self.__wrapped__.__self__.test_attr`, but all of them tell me:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'test_attr'
```

So how would I be able to access the decorated class' attribute in this case? Or will I have to use another way of building my decorators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're applying the decorator on an instance method, so the instance that this decorated method is bound to would be passed in as the first parameter, `self`, which is where you can find the instance attribute you're looking for, so you simply have to extract `self` from the arguments, named `wrapped_self` in the example below:

```
def __call__(self, wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs):
    tic = time.time()
    func_return = self.__wrapped__(wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs)
    tac = time.time()
    total_time = round((tac - tic) / 60, 2)
    print(f'Operation Time: {total_time} min.')
    print(wrapped_self.test_attr)
    return func_return
```

Comment: Very elegant and simple solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

"self" is the first parameter of do_something function.

So you can explicitly identify it inside your decorator.
`wrapped` will be the decorated class instance, and `*args` will contain all other positional arguments.

```
from functools import wraps
import types
import time

class TimeDecorator():

    def __init__(self, func):
        wraps(func)(self)

    def __call__(self, wrapped, *args, **kwargs):
        tic = time.time()
        func_return = self.__wrapped__(wrapped, *args, **kwargs)
        tac = time.time()
        total_time = round((tac - tic) / 60, 2)
        print(f'Operation Time: {total_time} min.')
        print(wrapped.test_attr)
        return func_return

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, instance)


class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.test_attr = 0

    @TimeDecorator
    def do_something(self):
        time.sleep(1) # example of stuff only...



a = A()
a.do_something()
```

Comment: Your answer is basicaly the same as @blhsing, but he posted it approximately 11 minutes before you. So, unfortunately for you, I'm gonna give the points to him. I'm gonna upvote your answer at least!